# SCC for Synchronous Generator Using Matlab

Tags: short-circuit, matlab, electric-machine, synchronous, simulink

What should I put in ''Three-Phase
Programmable
Voltage Source'' block ?[image]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Your goal of modeling here.

Comment: can't tell you what to put in a parameter field without knowing what the thing you're parameterizing is supposed to do. You will need to describe extensively what the objective of your model is, and what you have understood and considered so far.

Comment: not modeling. The question is to find Isc @ different values of Vdf. Actually, I found that Isc inc. while Vdf is increasing ,but they are not realistic. @relayman357

Comment: the objective is to find Isc at different values of Vdf. Actually, I found that Isc inc. while Vdf is increasing ,but they are not realistic. @MarcusMüller

Comment: OK, it looks to me like that voltage source just represents infinite bus to which your generator is connected.

Comment: exactly. @relayman357

Comment: so can you please tell me the parameter of the 3 phase block ? @relayman357

Comment: the following link describe the experiment. @relayman357      https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498572/open-circuit-test-and-short-circuit-test

Comment: the following link describe the experiment. @MarcusMüller    https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/498572/open-circuit-test-and-short-circuit-test

Answer (score 0):

I would start out with a voltage that matches your machine.  Vars flow from higher voltage to lower, so as you change this system voltage you should see corresponding change in var flow.  Power flow is controlled predominately by phase angle.  So, as you play with that you should see changes in power flow.  See [this link](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/examples/synchronous-machine.html) for more clues.

The link you gave in your comments above seems very explicit in detail.  Including giving the values you are talking about.

To apply a short circuit you need your voltage source to go to zero (on whatever phases you want to fault, or all 3 if three-phase fault).